# Boot from an External Drive that was Dual-Booted

Tags: hard-drive, boot, external-hard-drive, multi-boot

I had an HDD in my laptop which was dual-booted with Ubuntu and Windows 10.
I replaced it with an SSD which is also dual booted. I just plucked the hard drive from the back and made it an external drive.

The problem is I am needing some files that are there in the Ubuntu part of HDD. But when I plugged it in, the storage showed only Windows 10 partitions (strangely adding up to full space).

I still have the long option of putting the HDD back there again. But, the laptop is not very easy for it.

Can you please suggest me as to how I can do this.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: But when I plugged it in, the storage showed only Windows 10 partitions (strangely adding up to full space).    .....  Probably at this point, put the old drive back in and get the files that way. I have had to do this. Better to have the files.

Comment: @John Yeah that seems so. Also, is it the inablility of showing the Linux partitions that Windows 10 drives add up to full HDD space.